# Failed when build spring3 framework with gradle

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, gradle

I tried to build spring 3 framework using gradle, in ubuntu 12.04. but there was an error when build aspects progress.
the error is as follow:

```
spring-aspects:compileJava
Download http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.6.12/aspectjtools-1.6.12.jar
[ant:iajc] <Unknown> [warning] Found @DeclareAnnotation while current release does not support it (see 'org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.AtAjAttributes')
[ant:iajc]  
:spring-aspects:classes
:spring-aspects:jar
:spring-expression:javadoc
/home/hendri/spring-framework/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/OpMultiply.java:28: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
 * <p>If any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion (�5.1.8) is performed. Then:<br>
                                                                          ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-expression:javadoc'.
> Javadoc generation failed.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 24 mins 10.5 secs
```

can somebody help me to pass this error and build the spring 3 framework?? 
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try update the Spring code. If that not works take a look at what encoding are you compiling against.

Comment: that not work, but i tried  to redownload from svn, and try to build the new one, and it work.. 
i don't know why, but it works :D

thanks for your help :D/